# Standard deviation transformation sd(X-Y)

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation, variance

just need some help in this statistics question regarding the transformation of standard deviations.

This is the question:

> Let R be the visual acuity readings for the right eye of a randomly selected person and L be the corresponding visual acuity readings for the left eye. It was found that the standard deviation of the right eye readings was 0.2 and the standard deviation of the left eye readings was 0.1.
>   The standard deviation of the difference in visual acuity readings (R - L) is:

```
        unable to be determined from the information given.
        0.224
        0.1
        0.3
        0.173
```

first off I thought that the answer would be 0.1732 by converting it into the variance then do the subtraction then turn it back to sd by square rooting it...but when i submitted the answer it was wrong.

then upon further readings I realised that var(x-y)=var(x+y) which would give me the answer of 0.224. I submitted that answer and it was wrong AGAIN.

Now i'm just extremely confused and not too sure what the answer would be and why.

would really appreciate your help!! :)

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\v}{\operatorname{var}}$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{sd}(X-Y) = \sqrt{\v(X-Y)} = \sqrt{\v(X) + \v(Y) -2\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)}
\end{align}
This reduces to $\sqrt{\v(X) + \v(Y)}$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent or if the covariance is otherwise $0.$

You have $\v(X-Y) = \v(X) + \v(Y)$ if $X,Y$ are independent.

What you wrote was $\v(X-Y) = \v(X+Y)$ instead of $\v(X-Y) = \v(X)+\v(Y).$ It is also correct if written that way, but not useful in this case, since you need to add the variances. The difference between what you wrote and the one in which you add the variances is the kind of thing you need to pay attention to if you're doing mathematics.

It seems implausible to me that the two variables involved would actually be independent, but that could be assumed in an exercise.